# Can I perform chi-square test between a dichotomous variable and a categorical variable with more than two categories?

Tags: chi-squared-test, ordinal-data

My dependent variable is 'Malnutrition' (Yes, No).
Independent variable is 'Wealth-index' (Poor, Poorer, Middle, Richer, Richest).

Can I perform a chi-square test with 'Malnutrition' and 'Wealth-index'?

Comment: Yes, provided expected counts in most of the ten cells are above 5 and all ten are above 3.  (Some implementations of chi-squared tests relax these requirements by simulating the P-value, rather than risking a bad fit to the chi-squared distribution--in this case--with 4 degrees of freedom.) The hull hypothesis would be that probability of Malnutrition is the same regardless of Wealth category.

Comment: What's your alternative hypothesis? If you expect a monotonic effect from increasing Wealth, it would be throwing away information to ignore the ordering in that category.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do so, assuming the expected counts in each cell are large enough (all larger than one, not more than 20% smaller than 5). But it seems that your wealth category variable is ordinal, the usual chi-squared test would not use that information. To use it you can try ordinal logistic regression (search this site).